# Android: ImageButton with a dynamic size and fixed position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imagebutton

In my app I want set an ImageButton in a position in this way

[image]

and I want adapt this button in this way for all screen, is there a strategy to obtain it?

Comment: How many layouts u want to add ImageButton?Make each of the layout's root as Relative and make 1 separate footer layout in which this ImageButton..U need to just include footer in each of layout..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many screens you have that should have this button, how they interact with each other and whether the button should have the same funtion in every screen, but one option would be to have only one Activity with a layout, where you have the button on the bottom and an empty Layout above the button that works as fragment-container. Instead of starting new activities for a new "screen" change the Fragment in this container. The Button is always at the same place and you can handle its onClick centrally in the Activity...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  android:align = "Center"
```

or

```
 android:width ="0dp"
 android:weight = "1"
```

Comment: for small screen put low pixel image in drawable-mdpi folder with same name.

Answer (score 0):

BPut ImageView in `RelativeLayout` and set attrs for image view like that:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/previewImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```